# ftp reverse proxy using haproxy

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, reverse-proxy, haproxy

is it possible to have ftp reverse proxy like http

example

```
 client >> proxy >> real server
```

i have tried using haproxy

but at the end the real ip of the ftp server is exposed not like http reverse proxy

i am using this with haproxy

```
listen FTP :21, :10000-10250
    mode tcp
    server ftp01 realserverip:21 check port 21
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Haproxy does not understand the FTP protocol, and therefore can't do things like re-write the FTP commands and responses that include the true IP address of the FTP server.

If that's a requirement, then you'll have to find a different proxy solution.

Comment: any idea how this can done ?

Comment: Our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) can be used as an FTP reverse proxy,.  Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.  It's windows only, so I don't know if that would work for you.

Comment: thanks but i need something for linux